# Does the Compile method of the .NET XmlSchemaSet class resolve ref attributes for elements in the contained schemas?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

In a more general sense, I'd like to have a better idea what exact effects the compilation has. The MSDN documentation is unfortunately a bit unclear on the subject (at least, from what I could find, maybe I was managing to miss a page that clarifies everything).

In the more immediate sense, my concern is: when parsing through an XML schema that I have loaded into an XmlSchemaSet, do I need to manually resolve any potential elements that make use of the ref attribute or can I expect the Compile method to have resolved these and substituted the appropriate global element (or in the case of a group in a complexType, the appropriate sequences, choice, etc. that the group defined) into the properties of the XmlSchemaElement or XmlSchemaType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is yes, after poking around in the XmlSchemaSet source code. Here's the relevant snippet from the compiler code (unless I'm gravely misunderstanding, it looks like it copies over the Type and declaration from the referenced element):

```
if (!xe.RefName.IsEmpty) {
                XmlSchemaElement e = (XmlSchemaElement)elements[xe.RefName];
                if (e == null) {
                    throw new XmlSchemaException(Res.Sch_UndeclaredElement, xe.RefName.ToString(), xe);
                }  
                CompileElement(e);
                if (e.ElementDecl == null) {
                    throw new XmlSchemaException(Res.Sch_RefInvalidElement, xe.RefName.ToString(), xe);
                }
                xe.SetElementType(e.ElementSchemaType);
                decl = e.ElementDecl.Clone();
            }
            else { ...
```